# zabbix 3.2 - How to monitor RHEL7.2 services in zabbix

Tags: linux, monitoring, service, zabbix, system-monitoring

I am new in zabbix monitoring. I have 2 operation system to monitor windows and Linux and i have done monitoring windows services but i not getting any result on google to monitor linux server services.

I want to monitor service status, its CPU and RAM utilization. I have done some research i found some thing but its not gonna work

```
net.tcp.service['redis-server'] // its not working 
net.tcp.listen[6379] // its return the status for service but dont want to use
```

I want to monitor services based on service name like i did in windows

```
service.info[redis-server,state]
```

its working in my windows Please help for Linux services monitoring

Answer (score 0):

Use 3rd party Zabbix agent module for systemd - https://github.com/cavaliercoder/zabbix-module-systemd